# Access ApplicationScoped bean through ServletContext

Tags: jsf, quartz-scheduler

I have an ApplicationScoped bean that I'd like to access in a quartz job implementation.
That bean holds a hashmap through run-time and I'd like to populate the hashmap when the job runs.
However, the FacesContext is out of context inside the job. 
I have access to the ServletContext. Is it possible to access my bean through the ServletContext?

My code to access the Servlet Context:

```
@Override
public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

    SchedulerContext schedulerContext=null;
    try {
        schedulerContext=context.getScheduler().getContext();
    }
    catch (SchedulerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ServletContext servletContext=(ServletContext)schedulerContext.get("QuartzServletContext");
    BOCacheM bOCacheM = (BOCacheM) servletContext.getAttribute("bOCacheM");
}
```

My QuartzServletContext is defined in web.xml as:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>quartz:scheduler-context-servlet-context-key</param-name>
    <param-value>QuartzServletContext</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Quartz Scheduler and those things use their own thread to run. Looks like some design concerns. The answer is solely dependent upon the functional requirements which are invisible in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's stored as an attribute in `ServletContext`. Obtain it like any other attribute:

```
YourApplicationScopedBean bean = servletContext.getAttribute("yourApplicationScopedBeanName");
//use it...
```

If `bean` is `null` then looks like your bean wasn't created when the quartz job started. Make sure the bean is created by adding `eager=true` to its definition:

```
@ManagedBean(eager=true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class YourApplicationScopedBean {
    //...

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        //initialize your shared resources here...
    }
}
```

Note that `eager=true` only applies for `@ApplicationScoped` beans.

If this still doesn't work, seems like your quartz job is being fired even before the bean is created and stored in the application context. It would be better to initialize this resource in the `ServletContextListener` rather than in an `@ApplicationScoped` bean and provide access to this resource through another component.

Comment: Oddly, eager=true does not seem to be be working. The bean is not instantiated when the job runs. Through debugging I've seen the servletContext attributes and my bean is not part of it. Maybe I'm getting the servletContext wrong.

Comment: I would recommend you to create this `Map` in a class implementing `ServletContextListener#initialize` rather than in your application scoped bean or in a third element like a cache library (Infinispan, EhCache, whatever you like). Note that quartz doesn't fire a HTTP request so it's a bad design that your quartz jobs access to any of the web components e.g. `ServletContext`, `HttpServletSession`, `Servlet` in general...

Comment: If the job was the only way I'd be accessing the hash, I'd think your suggestion was correct. However, I have a xhtml file where the hashmap is listed and I have a button that updates the hash so I kind of need it to be in a bean. I appreciate your help though.

Comment: @Rita you can consume it from your quartz jobs and let your managed beans change it. It will ave an additional cost (like 10 to 50 ms) to perform the changes in the beans because now they have to access to this resource rather than directly to `ServletContext` but still it's not that hard.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why I can't find the bean inside the servletContext. Is it possible that I might be accessing my ServletContext in a wrong manner?

Comment: @Rita we may know if you provide the relevant code to analyze the problem.